# Appending a Dataframe with a Row from Another that Has Most But Not All of Same Columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe:

```
df1 one   two   three   four   five

A   6.3    7.1   tree    male   green
B   5.3    8.3   log     male   red
C   8.6    8.3   bark    female blue
.....
```

I also have a second df.  df2 has most but not all of the columns of df1. :

```
df2 one  two three    

D   9.3  3.4  cherry 
G   4.5  3.2  Apple
```

What is the easiest and most pythonic way to append a single row of df2 to df1?

I want to get this:

```
df1 one   two   three   four   five

A   6.3    7.1   tree    male   green
B   5.3    8.3   log     male   red
C   8.6    8.3   bark    female blue
D   9.3  3.4  cherry      Nan    Nan
```

I'm literally doing it column by column where the real df1 has about 25 columns and the df2 has about 20 columns.

So my syntax looks like this

```
df1.loc['D','one'] = df2.loc['D','one']
df1.loc['D','two'] = df2.loc['D','two']
....
```

This is terribly inefficient.  Is there a way to do this other than element-wise?  I can't think of how a method like `update` would apply here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your series look like a data frame.. Is how is it really like?

Comment: @Windstorm1981 I'm confused. Is the object you're trying to append to the original df a dataframe or a series?

Comment: @wpercy sorry for the confusion.  I have edited.  Hope its clearer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `concat` or `append` :

```
df = pd.concat([df1,df2[df2.index=='D']], sort=False)
```

Or:

```
df = df1.append(df2[df2.index=='D'], sort=False)
```

---

```
print(df)
   one  two   three    four   five
A  6.3  7.1    tree    male  green
B  5.3  8.3     log    male    red
C  8.6  8.3    bark  female   blue
D  9.3  3.4  cherry     NaN    NaN
```

**Note :** for both `concat` and `append` `sort` parameter is present in `pandas >= 0.23.0`, if your using lower version remove it.

Comment: This solution adds all rows of df2 but the problem is to add a single row

Comment: I thought to append the dataframes need to have identical columns?

Comment: @Windstorm1981 No, you don't need to check the documentation [`append`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html)